# How to make magnifying glass icon in SearchBar Visible?

Tags: c#, android, ios, .net, xaml

I'm using .NET MAUI and don't know how to create custom renderer for SearchBar. Currently, I can't see the magnifying glass icon in my physical phone (Android) when I test it out and want to make it visible and change the color to #ffca73. I want this for both Android and iOS but have no idea how to approach this problem. This is what I had for Android SearchBar custom renderer that I coded but it didn't work. I still can't see the magnifying glass icon at all.

```
public class CustomSearchBarRenderer : SearchBarRenderer
    {
        public CustomSearchBarRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SearchBar> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                // Change the color of the magnifying glass icon
                int searchIconId = Control.Resources.GetIdentifier("android:id/search_mag_icon", null, null);
                var searchIcon = Control.FindViewById(searchIconId);
                if (searchIcon is ImageView imageView)
                {
                    int color = AndroidColor.ParseColor("#ffca73");  // Use AndroidColor
                    imageView.SetColorFilter(new AndroidColor(color), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn);  // Use AndroidColor
                }
            }
        }
    }
```